# RewriteRule to get two variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my public_html I have a *profile.php* file and some links in this format

```
domain.com/shop/index.php?c=amazon&id=2
```

that lead to the amazon shop with category id 2

In a folder inside public_html, named *shop* I have *index.php* that shows the products of the 2 category.

However instead of the above ugly link I want to have something in the format of

```
domain.com/shop/company/category-id
e.g. domain.com/shop/amazon/2
```

I don't want to have *profile.php* and *shop.php* in the same folder because I have another RewriteRule in there.

What is the RewriteRule I have to use in this case of two variables? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a `.htaccess` file in the `shop` directory that include the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?c=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: Worked great. One more thing though. How can I have it in the form of `company/shop/2` instead of `shop/company/2` without having a different folder for each company? Is that possible ?

Comment: It is ok the shop/index.php to become shop.php and put it in the public_html folder, but I have this `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ company-profile.php?cid=$1 [NC,L]` already

Comment: Yes. But you'd have to move the `.htaccess` file to the root instead of the `shop` directory and change the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/shop/(\d+)$ /shop/index.php?c=$1&id=$2` assuming that the actual `index.php` will continue to be in a folder named `shop`.

Comment: As for that other comment, that's file. Just add the line above that other RewriteRule.  You can have many of those. The part after the RewriteRule is a regular expression that matches the `REQUEST_URI` from the user. The company profile matches letters or numbers only without any slashes or additional characters.

Comment: I get the logic behind this. Really thank you. It will help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?c=$1&id=$2
```

Or you you could move the `index.php` back into `public_html` and name it `shop.php`, and do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shop/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ shop.php?c=$1&id=$2
```